# Cannot add extra language under Android Secure Folder

Tags: languages, samsung-galaxy-a5

I use Samsung Galaxy A5 (2017) with Secure Folder.

So far I need to add extra language (English is primary one) Android starts to download but nothing is downloading under super-fast WiFi.

I am sure this is a Secure Folder issue.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
You have to download new language by Secure Folder Settings menu and NOT by keyboard settings icon within any installed apps of Secure Folder.